"Build only if new commits were pushed to Merge Request" flag from Gitlab plugin in Freestyle Jenkins job seem to be not working
The goal is to make only pushes to some Gitlab Merge request to trigger the related Jenkins CI job.
However by using the flag "Build only if new commits were pushed to Merge Request" from Gitlab plugin for Jenkins the job is still triggered for any pushes to any branch.
There is a tiny suspicion that the issue could be in the following topic, where the ref spec value cannot be set with the recommended value by documentation
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-73527
Jenkins and plugins versions report:
Jenkins 2.452.3
Gitlab plugin 1.8.1
Environment:
Jenkins installed on Mac OS X Ventura 13.5.2
Reproduction steps:
Create a Webhook on Gitlab with the following config:

Push events (All branches)
Comments
Merge request events

Create a Jenkins Freestyle job which is linked to this web hook and config it the following way:

Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab webhook URL: http://****
and the config:
Push events
Opened Merge requests
Merge request events
Build only if new commits were pushed to Merge Request
Approved merge requests

Expected Results:
The job is triggered only if
MR is created
The push is made to the MR branch
Actual Results:
The job is triggered whenever any push to any branch is done
